# Best Practices for Wiki library navigation

Tags: search, navigation, wiki, enterprise-wiki, metadata-navigation

I've been tasked with creating a Wiki Library for the company, but am struggling to find best practices to allow for easy user navigation. Essentially, what i'm after is the ability for users to easily navigate between pages within a Wiki , whilst on the Wiki Pages themselves.

Currently, I have a Wiki library on the Team Site and added a few pages. I've also enabled enterprise keyword searching, and created a new Term Set which is selectable in a managed metadata column. I've then set this term set as the quick links (side bar)

I've identified the following possibilities for navigation:

1) Create links within the page to other pages by using [[link]]..

2) Directing users to "View all Pages" and sort, filter, search using the list.

3) "Managed metadata" navigation, which replaces the links in the Quick Links (side bar) with the managed term set. I've found this to be good for managing the labels/ links from a centralized location. At the moment this is what is currently implemented

Any guidance on other ideas will be much appreciated,

cheers

Comment: when you say Wiki, do you mean Enterprise Wiki type of pages that usually sit in an Enterprise wiki site? Just to understand what you are using

Comment: Previously, I had a Wiki Library on the team site. This was like a document library which only held aspx pages. Yesterday however, I started a new Enterprise Wiki library as I like the idea of being able to select categories directly on the Enterprise wiki page. Just edited the main description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enterprise Wiki default page is different from all other types of pages as it carries on it the star rating and the ability to add categories to be able to filter pages by topics/categories. It was thought out as the type of page/site for a Knowledge base kind of repository. It is the only page that carries on top the last modified date and last editor, without forcing you to go in the library or in the properties. Outside the Enterprise wiki template this type of page can only be added to another publishing site, it cannot be added to a team site.

In the Enterprise wiki site template there is also another page content type called Project page which has the rating, the categories and a customizable field called STATUS to state if the page is completed or in progress. This field can be changed to your use to state something else. It has also a free space where you can add an URL (a different one for every page).

Both pages respond to the 'category' field which can be further edited in the Term Store of the site if you want to add a hierarchical structure to your terms as opposed to a flat list.

If you decide to go with the categories on the right side of the page, your point 3 is redundant as the navigation of the categories will be enough.

To be honest I have never seen this site template used properly mostly due to misuse, ignorance, lack of training and laziness (as for anything else in SharePoint). This site template is now more than 10 years old and I do not see Microsoft revamping it, however I always thought it had a lot of potential and if properly advertised it could be the solution to many documentation problems.

Comment: Thanks Susan, that pretty much summed up my thoughts on Enterprise Wiki pages. My intentions are to use it as a knowledge base. The Categories on the side come in handy, but they are only available on a page which has the category assigned. I've come to the conclusion that Managed Metadata Navigation will work best for this (as there is a deep hierarchy of terms) but then again thats anotehr learning curve